# Interactive computer

Tags: meaning

I am in class 6. I am presently reading my computer book.

> Game console is an interactive computer.

What is the meaning of *interactive*?

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes but could not understand it in this context. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactive is defined by the dictionary as:

> **of or relating to a two-way system of electronic communications, as by means of television or computer**

([Source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interactive))

So in this context, you can communicate with the games console, it responds to your actions. Say if you have a controller connected to it and you click a button, the console does something because you pressed the button and is hence interactive.